# Concrete5 pretty URL's (mod_rewrite) stopped working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, concrete5

I manage two websites, both running the Concrete5 CMS (v5.6.3.4) which uses an .htaccess file to rewrite the URL's so the 'index.php' file is hidden and the URL's look a lot better. Similar to what Wordpress does. The .htaccess content added by Concrete5 is:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

This used to work fine, but now only the homepage is reachable. When I visit one of the webpages like `/contact` a `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` is returned and I'm redirected to the homepage.

When I visit `/index.php/contact` the contact page loads correctly. 
I also tried the Wordpress rewrite rules and that gave the same result.

It looks like it stopped working because of some Apache, PHP or mod_rewrite module version change or something by my hosting company.
The sites run on Apache 2.4.17 and PHP 5.5.30. I can't discover the mod_rewrite module version.

I also tried the Apache `FallbackResource /index.php` and that seemed to work for the sub pages, but in that case the homepage failed loading.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**:

The Apache loaded modules are:

core mod_authn_file mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_anon mod_authn_dbd mod_authn_socache mod_authn_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_user mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_owner mod_authz_dbd mod_authz_core mod_access_compat mod_auth_basic mod_auth_form mod_auth_digest mod_allowmethods mod_file_cache mod_cache mod_cache_disk mod_cache_socache mod_socache_shmcb mod_socache_dbm mod_socache_memcache mod_so mod_macro mod_dbd mod_dumpio mod_buffer mod_ratelimit mod_reqtimeout mod_ext_filter mod_request mod_include mod_filter mod_substitute mod_sed mod_deflate http_core mod_mime mod_log_config mod_log_debug mod_logio mod_env mod_expires mod_headers mod_unique_id mod_setenvif mod_version mod_remoteip mod_proxy mod_proxy_connect mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_fcgi mod_proxy_scgi mod_proxy_wstunnel mod_proxy_ajp mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_express mod_session mod_session_cookie mod_session_dbd mod_slotmem_shm mod_ssl mod_lbmethod_byrequests mod_lbmethod_bytraffic mod_lbmethod_bybusyness mod_lbmethod_heartbeat mod_unixd mod_dav mod_status mod_autoindex mod_info mod_suexec mod_cgi mod_dav_fs mod_dav_lock mod_vhost_alias mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir **mod_alias mod_rewrite** mod_php5 mod_ruid2 prefork

Comment: This answer http://serverfault.com/a/42551/141697 might help showing your configuration and investigating this further.

Comment: Thanks @OlafDietsche. I can create a phpinfo() page, but can't modify the httpd.conf file or restart Apache because the site is running on a shared web hosting platform controlled by the ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be related to an Apache upgrade.
The problem can be solved by adding:

define('SERVER_PATH_VARIABLE', 'REQUEST_URI');

to config/site.php

For details, please see here:
http://www.concrete5.org/developers/bugs/5-6-3-4/every-page-returns-page-not-found-except-home-page-with-pretty-u/

Credits are for user sandsoft of the Concrete5 forums!

Answer (score 0):

I run a similar apache / php version and the only difference I can see is this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Note the / in front of index.php. Try that, then add in the two extra conditions in yours, and see if it works.

Note, this is in .htaccess and in my actual virtual hosts file in apache.

Are you sure mod rewrite is enabled? Try a simple rule as a test:

```
RewriteRule ^xxx https://google.com [R=301,L]
```

before the rewrite block you have, save, restart apache (if it's not .htaccess), then try accessing: yoursite.com/xxx

If it works, and you end up on google, then rewrite is fine.

Also check phpinfo() if you haven't, you should see this, or something like it:

```
Configuration
apache2handler

Loaded Modules  core mod_so http_core [...] mod_alias mod_rewrite [...]
```

By the way, your provided data was excellent.

As far as I know, Apache and its modules ship together, at least the standard ones, though I could be wrong, but I believe most installations would be like that, so it's at least highly unlikely that there would be an issue there, but what is highly likely is that the hosting company  may have forgotten to turn on mod rewrite, I've seen that several times here with similar questions.

UPDATED:

I tested your urls with firefox live http headers:

```
GET /aanleg/ HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://yoursite.com
```

I first wrote your redirect is working fine, but it's not working fine, it's totally wrong, because there should be no redirect.

Since you ran phpinfo, php is also running.

You'll need to show your entire htaccess becuase you have a bad rule that is redirecting the url.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yoursite\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This is all you should have for rewrites unless you have specific ones, but there's clearly a rewrite rule that is sending everything to / which should NOT be happening.

UPDATE: this issue was determined almost certainly to be a concrete5 problem, not an apache redirect issue.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. I first tried the Google test. It worked, so mod_rewrite is working fine. Than I cleared the .htaccess file and added your condition and rules. Still get the same result. You can see it go wrong here: http://www.paulohouben.nl

Comment: Wait, no, I see it, the problem is in fact  the fact that it is redirecting the url. Something else is wrong in your htaccess, please post the entire thing.

Comment: I think you're right about the location of the problem being Concrete5. Apach/PHP and mod_rewrite are working correctly (based on the tests and results above). I don't use `DirectoryIndex` and there are no other index files than `index.php` in the root folder. Thanks for your precious time and effort.

Comment: Currently the whole .htaccess file contains only your stuff:  RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: I will try the htaccess content you just provided.

Comment: ok, that helps. I tested a wordpress with friendly urls and confirmed that you definitely should NOT be seeing that 301 redirect to the index.php page.  The issue seems to be that something is grabbing your urls and sending them to index.php.

Comment: I added your 7 lines as the only content (of course replaced the yoursite part with my domain name) but still no luck.

Comment: RewriteEngine On as the first line I assume. If that doesn't work then it's possible something else is redirecting without you knowing it. I've seen some registrars do this, for example, if improperly setup. It looks like something is simply grabbing all your urls and rewriting them to /. I would see if the web hoster has made a mistake. Test it this way. Make a directory called yyy then put the file index.html into it, with some text on it. See if you can acess yoursite.nl/yyy/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93892/discussion-between-maarten-docter-and-lizardx).

Answer (score 0):

The next version of the legacy (5.6) version of concrete5 won't suffer this problem: it has been fixed with https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-legacy/pull/1931